# Unable to install mysql workbench on 12.04 with synaptic, dependency error

Tags: mysql-workbench

Getting `Dependency is not satisfied libmysqlclient16 (>-5.1.21-1)`

[image]

How can I resolve that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just issued:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

at the command line at it was installed.

Choose it in the dash and up it comes:

[image]

It is version **5.2.38**

The current GA version is 5.2.40 so that looks good enough for me.

Comment: The version in the archives already will work.  Please use that, instead of cutting-edge.

Comment: but I got an error trying to use it!

Comment: what error(s) are you referring to?